# Laravel - Ajax Modal and Delete not working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I have an ajax and button delete but im wondering why the modal is not popping up. can you help me please.

I dont have the link also to ajax can you provide me what link should i have thanks

My **Button**

```
<button class="delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$client->id}}"
                    data-client_name="{{$client->client_name}}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
</button>
```

My ***Ajax***
Kindly check my ajax code I think im still missing some code thanks.

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
    $('#footer_action_button').text(" Delete");
    $('#footer_action_button').removeClass('glyphicon-check');
    $('#footer_action_button').addClass('glyphicon-trash');
    $('.actionBtn').removeClass('btn-success');
    $('.actionBtn').addClass('btn-danger');
    $('.actionBtn').addClass('delete');
    $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
    $('.did').text($(this).data('id'));
    $('.deleteContent').show();
    $('.form-horizontal').hide();
    $('.dname').html($(this).data('name'));
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/archTrashPermanent',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id': $('.did').text()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.item' + $('.did').text()).remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My ***Controller***

```
public function archTrashPermanent($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    if($client->forceDelete()){
    return redirect('/admin/clients')->with('success','Client and Information Removed !');
    }
}
```

Comment: type isn't post for the delete operation and you don't need any token for delete operation

Comment: im stuck at ajax haha. im having a hard time now

Comment: You need to look at how ajax works, method types, success/error function :D

Comment: Where is the modal?
Can you show the sent ajax request?